# MySQL way to store monthly revenue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, datetime

I want to store restaurant's monthly revenue (income and expenses), and later show it on a line graph for every year. I have come to this workaround [image: database diagram] I would store in `year` variable for example `2020-01-01` and then it should be adding values to all the following row for every month. Would it even work this way? Or should I use one `date` type and add months to it?

Comment: Well, definitely not this way. A database table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work, but it is not optimal.

For example if you want to see the yearly expenses you have to type every single month name into your query.

A more practical solution can be to use a single table with example columns like so:

- date
- is_expense (boolean)
- amount (double)
- restaurant_id

Where is_expense is boolean if the amount is income or expense.

You can aggregate from here everything: yearly / monthly expenses/incomes/profits etc.

You can use MySQL Functions like `MONTH(date)` that will give you specific month. For example if you want to aggregate all expenses for specific year & month you will do something similar to

`SELECT SUM(amount) from Table WHERE is_expense=1 AND MONTH(date) = 1 AND YEAR(date) = 2020`

Comment: Or you should store the expenses as negative values. You'll get a simplier schema, without is_expense column and the simpler use of SUM() or other aggregation methods and logic operations too.

Date will be tricky too, if you'd like to store some recurring expenses, like: "every first monday in a month" or similar.